# Android recyclerview dependency display error

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, dependencies

This is very default setting, first I create a dummy project, then click add recyclerview, then I click at recyclerview menu, the Android studio prompt to add the library, then I accept.

I click at okay, the dependency than update as following:
[image: I click at okay, the dependency than update as following]

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
```

and the error message as this
[image: this is the error message]

please be remind I use default android studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use the same version for `support libraries`.

either use `25.3.1` for both support libraries or use `26.0.0` for both support libraries.

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that all the support libraries you are using are of the same version and major version has to match compile SDK version.

As you yourself mentioned adding Google's Maven Repository solves the problem. For others,

> The most recent versions of the following Android libraries are
>   available from Google's Maven repository:

Add them like this:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
        // Alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it need add respitories                               
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }

Comment: My bad, the answer was based on the presumption you have already added that!